# Hosting with CUDA support

Tags: hosting, vps, cuda

One web application that I'm planning relies in [CUDA]http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html) for doing heavy math processing. I developed the software at home, but now I'm looking for deployment options. I know that Amazon  EC2 provides CUDA hosting, but their instances with CUDA are way too high end and a bit too expensive, at least for the testing stage I have up-front.

Anybody knows where can I get affordable CUDA hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [peer1](http://www.peer1.com/hosting/gpu-cloud.php) and [Hoopoe](http://www.hoopoe-cloud.com/). I don't think there are any other GPU clouds out there yet.

Comment: They don't say their price...

Comment: Well just email them.

Comment: I just did it. Not worth the cost. I will have to set it up at home. But thanks!

Comment: Or you could setup a machine yourself with some high end GPUs and collocate it at a data center (for network and environmental reliability)